# SQL syntax in insert into

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote this code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (user_id, word_id, right) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )") or die(mysql_error());
```

But an error message prompts:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )' at line 1

What I did wrong?

Comment: You should not use character literals for numbers. `'6'` is a character, `6` is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`right` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) , escape it like so:

```
INSERT INTO test (user_id, word_id, `right`) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )
```

**Note that:**<sup>1</sup>

> Use of this extension(mysql_query) is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
>   extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)  guide and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_query()
> PDO::query()
> ```

---

<sup>1:<sup>quoted from [**PHP Manual: mysql_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)</sup></sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! What are the other reserved words?

Answer (score 2):

`right` is reserved key word [`9.3. Reserved Words`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) when we use reserved keyword we need to escape them  try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (user_id, word_id, `right`) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )") or die(mysql_error());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :::`RIGHT` is known keyword, try a backtick

```
INSERT INTO test (`user_id`, `word_id`, `right`) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`user_id`, `word_id`, `right`) VALUES ('6', '23', '5' )
```